# Getting a version conflict error when compiling play-services-gcm:8.4.0

Tags: android, gradle, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Hello I am getting the following error when building my build gradle.

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)

Here is my build file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.games.ultimatetictactoe.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.1"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-token-generator:2.0.0'
}
```

I have been looking at several answers, but they were not totally clear on how I should fix my build gradle in order to fix this issue.

Comment: I fixed this by using 8.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Change your google-services in dependencies with

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha5'
```

Also since you are using the support libraries **v23** you have to compile with api 23.

Use

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Hey thanks. That really worked!!! I also changed the compiledSdkVersion and my app is running well thank you!!!!!

Comment: @JeanCarlosHenriquez Mark the answer if it solves your issue. It can help other users